# Adding 2 linked lists

Tags: python

The problem I have is to find the sum of 2 linked lists. Each linked list node contains 1 digit that represents a number.

My algorithm works but I was wondering if there is a more efficient (speed and memory wise) to solve this problem OR maybe some minor tweaks I can do to reduce space and runtime.

Example: `7 -> 5 -> 6 = 756`

I am trying to find the sum of 2 linked lists.

```
def addlist(LL1, LL2):
    storage = []
    multiplier = 1
    total = 0
    while LL1 != None:
        storage.append(LL1.data)
        LL1 = LL1.next
    for i in storage[::-1]:
        total += i*multiplier
        multiplier *= 10
    storage = []
    multiplier = 1
    while LL2 != None:
        storage.append(LL2.data)
        LL2 = LL2.next
    for j in storage[::-1]:
        total += j*multiplier
        multiplier *= 10
    return total
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't repeat yourself

Your method has the same code duplicated twice in it. You should always try to eliminate this kind of duplication, for example like this:

```
def addlists(LL1, LL2):
    return sumlist(LL1) + sumlist(LL2)

def sumlist(LL1):
    storage = []
    multiplier = 1
    total = 0
    while LL1 != None:
        storage.append(LL1.data)
        LL1 = LL1.next
    for i in storage[::-1]:
        total += i*multiplier
        multiplier *= 10
    return total
```

### Simplify

The logic can be simplified, a lot:

```
def sumlist(ll):
    total = 0
    while ll:
        total *= 10
        total += ll.data
        ll = ll.next
    return total
```

I also simplified the `None` comparison, instead of `if ll != None` you can write simply `if ll`

### Naming

The convention is to use lowercase variable names, so it would be better to change `LL1` and `LL2`.

Answer (score 1):

If L1 and L2 are list it can be done like following:

```
def addList(L1, L2):
 num1 = sum([L1[i]*(10**i) for i in range(len(L1)-1,-1,-1)])
 num2 = sum([L2[i]*(10**i) for i in range(len(L2)-1,-1,-1)])
 return num1 + num2
```

In your codes you just need L1.next to do the same work done by the loop in the given code.